# Oracle Regular expression to remove all charaters except those within Quotes and Dot

Tags: regex, oracle

How do I exclude all characters except those enclosed within double quotes and dot(.) using oracle regular expression?

**for example**

***Sample Input***

> "Abc"."EFG" is not the same as "EFG"."ABC"."FIJ"

***Expected output***

> "Abc"."EFG"           "EFG"."ABC"."FIJ"

Comment: Can you include what you have tried so far?

Comment: Is the period always between quoted strings?

Comment: More example data is needed. Show a sample of unique rows of real data if possible. Could the quoted strings be surrounded by text to be removed or just at the beginning/end as shown? Are the quoted strings always the same length?  Could quoted strings be adjacent? More info is needed before a regex can be created.

Answer (score 0):

this is my try:

```
WITH A AS
  (SELECT 'and "EFG"."ABC"."FIG" is not the same as "Abc"."EFG" bla' AS text FROM DUAL),
b as (
SELECT 
    text, 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, '("[[:alnum:]]*"\.)+"[[:alnum:]]*"',1,level) part, 
    level l
  FROM a
  connect by 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, '("[[:alnum:]]*"\.)+"[[:alnum:]]*"',1,level) is not null
  )
select listagg(b.part,' ') within group (order by l)
from b;
```

It extracts the expressions in format `("[[:alnum:]]*"\.)+"[[:alnum:]]*"` and concatenates them back.

It is not perfect, however your specification of the problem is not too rigorous.